# Realtime WordPress Backup Plugin

Tags: backup, wordpress, real-time

I'm looking for a WordPress plugin that takes real-time backups of both the file system and the database of the WordPress instance. I would like the plugin to meet these requirements:

- Does not use their own servers for backup - The plugin should be able to save backups on the server it is on or it can save it to a well-known file storage provider such as AWS, Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.
- Takes backups in real-time, as changes are made, the backup should immediately start. This should be done through something like incremental backups but if it takes full backups every time, that still would be acceptable.
- Up to date - I don't want a plugin that hasn't been updated in over 2 years.
- Is not [Blogvault](https://blogvault.net/) -  I'm looking for something relatively cheap or free, I'm hesitant at setting a price but for now let's keep it under $989.00 per year for a multi-site license
- Is not in beta

Some features that aren't requirements but wanted are:

- Gratis
- Able to send backups to on off-site storage provider specifically Amazon S3 buckets
- Takes incremental backups
- Uses Git

Comment: For $989 or less, you can hire a server admin on UpWork that can set up a master / slave db. For real time backups, I'm pretty sure you are not going to find a plugin. You could also ask hosting companies like WPEngine if they could do this for you. Personally, I would not leave this to a plugin.